# How to sort JSON based on 2 columns?

Tags: json, sorting

I have bellow JSON:

```
[
    {"trip_id":2, "lat":100, "lon":200, "location_seq":0},
    {"trip_id":2, "lat":200, "lon":400, "location_seq":1},
    {"trip_id":3, "lat":300, "lon":300, "location_seq":1},
    {"trip_id":3, "lat":400, "lon":400, "location_seq":0}
]
```

and trying to sort it first on 'trip_id' column ascending and then on 'location_seq' ascending. In SQL would do at the end of query with:

```
order by trip_id, location_seq
```

How to achieve the same within JSON using JavaScript? Goal is to iterate trough above data as is sorted by trip_id and location_seq (so not necessary need to be JSON at the end - just to have correct sequence).

Thanks.

Comment: Please verify; the correct sequence of your example array would be 0, 1, 3, 2?

Comment: For location_seq there are only 2 possibilities (0 and 1) - meaning 0 is Start and 1 is End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trips = [
  {"trip_id":2, "lat":100, "lon":200, "location_seq":0},
  {"trip_id":2, "lat":200, "lon":400, "location_seq":1},
  {"trip_id":3, "lat":300, "lon":300, "location_seq":1},
  {"trip_id":3, "lat":400, "lon":400, "location_seq":0}
];

trips.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.trip_id !== b.trip_id)
    return a.trip_id - b.trip_id;
  return a.location_seq - b.location_seq;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. Hope it will help you.

```
var obj = [
{"trip_id":2, "lat":100, "lon":200, "location_seq":0},
{"trip_id":2, "lat":200, "lon":400, "location_seq":1},
{"trip_id":3, "lat":300, "lon":300, "location_seq":1},
{"trip_id":3, "lat":400, "lon":400, "location_seq":0}
]

obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a["trip_id"] - b["trip_id"] || a["location_seq"] - b["location_seq"];
});
```